# using notificationcenter with performselector

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

I want to get notifications on non-main thread from notificationcenter.
is there any way I can use performselector onThread when adding observer to NotificationCenter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up a `NSOperationQueue` using the `dispatch_queue_t` you want to process notifications on. Here's an example of registering for current locale changed notification:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        //You need to set this variable to the queue you want the blocks to run on if not on default background queue
        dispatch_queue_t queueToPostTo = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        //Properties being used
        //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject * localeChangeObserver;
        //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue * localChangeObserverQueue;

        self.localChangeObserverQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [self.localChangeObserverQueue setUnderlyingQueue:queueToPostTo];

        NSNotificationCenter * notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        self.localeChangeObserver =  [notificationCenter addObserverForName:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                                     object:nil
                                                                      queue:self.localChangeObserverQueue
                                                                 usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                                     //Your code here for processing notification. 
                                                                 }];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSNotificationCenter * notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self.localeChangeObserver];
}
```